# Add (or multiply, subtract or divide) one var to another in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

Sincere apologies if this has been asked and answered elsewhere, I struggled with finding accurate search terms for this.

Working in jQuery I have a `var` called `total`. I need to add the value of other `vars` to `total`. All the `vars` in question have numerical values.

This is what I've tried:

```
var total = total+rocketspend;
$(".totalamount").html(total);
```

and

```
var newtotal = total+rocketspend;
var total = newtotal;
$(".totalamount").html(total);
```

Both have resulted in `.totalamount` being emptied and replaced with nothing. I have theories around why this might be going wrong - it could be that in the first example a `var` isn't allowed to be self defining, and it could be that in in the second example the browser attempts to define both `newtotal` and `total` at the same time, ending in mystery. Or it could be something else entirely. The `rocketspend` `var` works fine on its own, as does `total` before the attempted addition.

Thoughts?

Comment: What are the values of `total` and `rocketspend`? A little more of your code would help

Comment: what are the types of these variables? ie String, Number etc

Comment: Thanks guys, the answer below was correct. They were numbers defined by the user through use of forms on the page.

Comment: EDIT: I spoke too soon - the code below doesn't add the two numbers together in a mathematical sense, but as a string. So if the vars being added are 3 and 9, the desired result is "12", but the produced result is "39"

Comment: See my post on string and number values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use `var` when you first define a variable. It looks like you're trying to access a variable that already exists. Example:

```
var total = 0;
var rocketspend = 10;

total = total + rocketspend;
$(".totalamount").html(total);
```

Additionally, try checking your console for any errors. In most browsers, you can right click and inspect an element or click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and clicking on the Console tab. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in Firefox.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. That fixed it. Console wasn't giving any errors for some reason. Apparently I can't mark your answer correct for another 6 minutes.

Comment: Strange... I was about to delete this answer because I realized that shouldn't matter since you're creating a new `total` variable, but the expression still refers to the previous one. And when I tested it, adding the `var` keyword still works. Glad I helped... I guess? I would check the rest of your code, as it might be a reference error elsewhere.

Comment: EDIT: I spoke too soon - the code below doesn't add the two numbers together in a mathematical sense, but as a string. So if the vars being added are 3 and 9, the desired result is "12", but the produced result is "39"

Comment: That's JS typing for you. Make sure your variables are in fact numbers. You can convert them using `parseInt(string)`, `+string`, or `string*1`.

Comment: Weirdly it was the var I least suspected that was being treated as a string rather than a number. Anyway, we've gotten to the bottom of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery and have referenced an element (i.e. `.totalamount`) so assuming you are using normal webpage (i.e. HTML, CSS, JS/jQ etc..), this Snippet has 2 `<forms>`. The first one uses only JavaScript and HTML5. The second form uses jQuery and HTML5.

When using form fields such as `<input>`, the value you type in them will be a string (i.e. text) value. So when "3" is typed in, the `<input>` will treat it as text not a real number value. So convert the string to a number, use `parseFloat()`, `parseInt()`, or `Number()`.

To get `<input>` values use `.val()` (jQuery) or `.value` (JavaScript).

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('#calc1').on('input', function() {
  var rocket1 = $('#rocket1').val();
  var sub1 = $('#sub1').val();
  var total1 = parseFloat(sub1) + parseFloat(rocket1);
  $("#total1").val(total1);
});
```

```css
input {width: 8ex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Using only plain JavaScript and HTML5 form fields</p>
<form id="calc" name="calc" oninput="total.value = parseFloat(sub.value, 10) + parseFloat(rocket.value, 10)">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rocket Expenditure</legend>
    <label for="sub">
      <b>Sub Total:</b>
      <input type="number" id="sub" name="sub" value="0">
    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="rocket">
      <b>Rocket:</b>
      <input type="number" id="rocket" name="rocket" value="0">
    </label>
    <label>
      <b>Total:</b>
      <output name="total" for="sub rocket">0</output>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p>Using jQuery and HTML5 form fields</p>
<form id="calc1" name="calc1">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Rocket Expenditure 1</legend>
    <label for="sub1">
      <b>Sub Total 1:</b>
      <input type="number" id="sub1" name="sub1" value="0">
    </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="rocket1">
      <b>Rocket 1:</b>
      <input type="number" id="rocket1" name="rocket1" value="0">
    </label>
    <label>
      <b>Total 1:</b>
      <output id="total1" name="total1" for="sub1 rocket1">0</output>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```